# Confusion regarding some Islamic statements, need clarification if you're so be kind enough as I'm in real need

Tags: quran, practical-islam, hadith-interpretation, belief

I have a little confusion regarding several Islamic  statements (confusion mean I'm ignorant about those matters)
, the following are the statements, as I'm a laymen, don’t know where these statements  have been said, they could be from both Quran and hadith:

***1.*** The person will lead a very **miserable** life who neglects the remembrance of Allah.

***2.*** This world is a **prison** for the believers.

***3.*** This world is an **amusement** for the disbelievers. [seems contradictory with no.***1***]

***4.*** Jannah is surrounded by things that aren’t desirable.

***5.*** Jahannam is surrounded by things that are desirable and attractive acts/things (women, money, drugs and so on) that are generally the deeds of the disbelievers.

***6.*** Those who abide by the wills of Allah, surely Allah will give them a descent life in this world. [seems contradictory/opposite to no.***2***]

And so many other statements, I knew but can't recall them now,  that are similar to those that have been mentioned above.

***Question:*** **How** can it be possible that a disbeliever can have no. **1**, **3** and **5** at the same time in this life? **Isn’t** it contradictory or somewhat confusing that a believer will have to strive or live like a life as if they are in prison (i.e., no. ***2***) whilst Allah promised to give them a decent life in this world? **The** disbeliever will have a miserable life but at the same time another quote says, as they are gonna be in Hell in the hereafter (as an self-driving individual who is wrongdoer)  they live their worldly life having sin and desirable forbidden things meaning enjoying life the most!? **I** want a simple knowledge based explanation for these statements cause the more I think about them the more I got confusion and at the same time I fear that Saytan will start whispering into my mind and **try to deviate me! So please anyone could help me out.**